# How to have border .gif repeating on both left and right side of container div?

Tags: css

I've got a div that is fluid width depending on the browser.  I have a border image that I want to have on both the left and right side of the div.  How would I do that?  I have the left side working as needed:

```
#conten {

 background: #fff url(/images/pagebgleft.gif) top left repeat-y;
 color: #333333;
 float: none;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 1080px;
 margin: auto ;
 }
```

I want to use an image `url(/images/pagebgright.gif)` for the right side.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple backgrounds or put another wrapper `div` and set the right hand background to it.

Comment: How would I use multiple background there?

Comment: @Joel [If you don't have to support older IEs, it is great](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

Answer (score 1):

I may have posted too late. Each border needs to be in it's own div and absolutely positioned inside a relative position container. The background image I'm using happens to be an animated border gif i got from google.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="leftb"></div>   
    <div class="rightb"></div>   
</div>

.wrap{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.leftb, .rightb{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background: transparent url(http://www.capriogroup.com/webstuff/Images/Borders/Animated-Border-ChainLinksVertical.gif) repeat-y 0 0;
    color: #333333;
    width: 20px;
    height:400px;
}

.leftb {
    left:0;    
}

.rightb {
    right:0;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZxQ6Z/1/